# Remove perspective warping in react three fiber

Tags: three.js, next.js, react-spring, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to make a sphere that follows my cursor. Most of it is done, however, the sphere severely warps on the edges of my screen.

Middle of screen:
[image: Middle of screen]

Edge of screen:
[image: Edge of screen]

I have the default camera (fov changed) setup but I feel like it's the wrong one

Canvas:

```js
const Canvas: NextPage<CanvasProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const camera = { fov: 60, near: 0.1, far: 1000, position: [0, 0, 5] }

  return (
    <ThreeCanvas className="bg-gray-900" camera={camera}>
      {children}
      <Mouse />
    </ThreeCanvas>
  )
}
```

Mouse.tsx:

```js
const Mouse: NextPage<MouseProps> = ({}) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false)
  const { viewport } = useThree()
  const { scale } = useSpring({ scale: active ? 0.7 : 1 })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (active) {
      setTimeout(() => setActive(false), 200)
    }
  }, [active])

  const ref = useRef()

  useFrame(({ mouse }) => {
    const x = (mouse.x * viewport.width) / 2
    const y = (mouse.y * viewport.height) / 2

    if (typeof ref !== undefined) {
      // @ts-ignore
      ref!.current.position.set(x, y, 0)
      // @ts-ignore
      ref!.current.rotation.set(-y, x, 0)
    }
  })

  return (
    <>
      <ambientLight />
      <pointLight position={[10, 10, 10]} />
      <animated.mesh scale={scale} onClick={() => setActive(!active)} ref={ref}>
        <sphereGeometry args={[0.15, 32, 32]} />
        <meshStandardMaterial color="beige" transparent />
      </animated.mesh>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: You can't avoid that distortion, using PerspectiveCamera. You can reduce it though, setting camera FOV to lesser values.

Comment: Like Prisoner said above, that's an expected behavior of a perspective camera with a wide FOV. You could try using an orthographic camera, but that comes with its own set of quirks, for instance, you'd lose depth scaling.